# Interbase DB: Unable to create requested service: Hibernate Session

Tags: hibernate, session, database-connection, interbase

I'm having difficulty getting a Hibernate Session to work when connecting to an Interbase DB. I can connect to the database through JDBC but I'm not sure why my Session fails to instantiate when trying to connect to Interbase.

Here's an extract of my method to connect to Interbase:

```
database connection:
URL configLoc = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
Properties props = new Properties();
try {
   databaseName =  "jdbc:interbase://v-ib/e:/db/44june.gdb";  
   configuration = new Configuration().configure(configLoc);
   configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", databaseName); 
   configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "HOST");
   configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "HOST");
   try{
      sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(); 
   } catch (Exception e2){
     System.out.println(e2.getMessage()); 
   }
  }
 }
 database = sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
```

...and here's my Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
Hibernate.cfg.xml :

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property    
   name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.InterbaseDialect</property>
  <property  
 name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">interbase.interclient.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset">true</property>
```

When I run the code, an exception is thrown on the line that attempts to build a 
sessionFactory:

configuration.buildSessionFactory();

and here's the Exception:

`Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason that this was failing was some settings left over from legacy code.  The best I can gather is that the Interbase class and dialect were not loading properly from the hibernate.cfg.xml.  Adding the following lines to the try{} block seemed to do the trick:

```
String dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.InterbaseDialect";
String driverClass = "interbase.interclient.Driver";
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.dialect", dialect);
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", 
  driverClass);
```